# Sharepoint 2010 - how do I add a page using code

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How do I add a new page on sharepoint using code?

I am coding site using SPservices, javascript and jquery

I pull the link from a List and use this variable to call the web page.
however if the page does not exist -- I will get page can not be displayed screen when I click on the on click event

is it possible to do the following?

1, check if the page exists
2, if page does not exist create a blank page

any help would be very grate full as I have searched online for days on end to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can add the pages by referring the below steps:

1.Create a new folder, "**Pages**", under your solution

2.Add a new module,for eg. **SampleModule**

[Module folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBgdE.png)

3.Add an application page, for eg. **SampleApplicaionPage.aspx**. The newly added application pages can be found under Layouts Folder.

4.Drag and drop the newly created aspx page into the created "**SampleModule**", under pages folder.

5.Make necessary changes (module name, required layout, etc.,) in the **element.xml** file associated with the module as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="Pages" Url="$Resources:cmscore,List_Pages_UrlName;">
<File Path="SampleModule\SampleApplicationPage.aspx" Url="SampleApplicationPage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="True">
<Property Name="Sample Module" Value="Sample Module"/>
<Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, EnterpriseWiki"/>
</File>
</Module>
</Elements>
```

6. Update the following section in the **SampleApplicationPage.aspx**

   *<%@ Page Language=”C#”
   AutoEventWireUp=”true”
   CodeBehind=”ChooseChecklist.aspx.cs”
   Inherits=”YourProjectName.YourModuleName.YourClassName”
   MasterPageFile=”../_catalogs/masterpage/V4.master” %>*
7. Deploy.

   You can view the newly created page under the specified module in Site Contents

Hope this helps.

[Final Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEMod.png)